# Python multiple classes

Tags: python

I want to create multiple bots with all their own unique id. But how can do this automatically for numerous bots and have all an other id? I can use bot1, bot2 but what if i want to use this with 100 bots?

```
class newbot:
    id = randomid()


bot1 = newbot() 
bot2 = newbot()   
print bot1.id
print bot2.id   #all the same id
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `id` member ends up being shared among all instances of your class because it's defined as a class member instead of an instance member. You probably should write:

```
class newbot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = randomid()

bot1 = newbot() 
bot2 = newbot()   

# The two ids should be different, depending on your implementation of randomid().
print bot1.id
print bot2.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Use built-in function *id()* for this. Construct new empty object and get id( obj ).

Or you can get *id( bot1), id( bot2 )*

Try the next:

```
  def getRandId( self ):
    return id( self )
```